# Spring Security: Migrating Self Closing Authentication Manager xml Tag to Java Config

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I have a fairly out-of-the-box Spring Security 3.2 J2EE xml config that I have almost finished converting to Java config.

The Before xml file:

```
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
<sec:authentication-manager />

<sec:http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
....
<sec:http auto-config="true" create-session="never" use-expressions="true>
    <sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />
    <sec:jee mappable-roles="admin,user" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/operations/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_admin')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
</sec:http>
```

The self closing authentication-manager tag is my issue. It's picking up the PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider created by the jee tag. I'm not quite sure how to replicate it in the Java Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@ImportResource("classpath:security-context.xml")
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception{
        web
            .ignoring.antMatchers("/css/**")
            .and()
            .ignoring.antMatchers("/js/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionFixation().none()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .jee()
            .mappableAuthorities("admin","user")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/operations/admin/**").hasAuthority("admin")
            .anyRequest.permitAll();
    }
}
```

This is working now only because I am importing my old security-context.xml which has nothing in it except the authentication-manager tag.

I have playing around with declaring an AuthenticationManagerBuilder bean, but it seems like everything requires a specific reference to an AuthenticationProvider or UserDetailsService to work. The ProviderManager default constructor is deprecated.

I know that the jee() entry adds the PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider to the sharedObjects inside HttpSecurity, so I could go through the trouble of getting the PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider out of the sharedObjects to create an AuthenticationManager if necessary, but it seems like there ought to be a simple Java config counterpart to the self-closing xml tag that I am just missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this on your SpringSecurityConfig class :-

```
@Autowired
public void registerGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
   auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationManagerBeanDefinitionParser.NullAuthenticationProvider());
}
```